# table border line is removed when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have created an application for printing a html table, The printing application is working fine, but the problem is that the table is designed in such a way that the border line is applied using css (i can't modify anything to the styles since it was been done by other team), so when i trigger the print option that css is not applied.

My code is as given below

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2d7otd1/)**

**html**

```
<table id="printTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Add/ Remove</td>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Add/ Remove</td>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Add/ Remove</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Add/ Remove</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<br />
<br />

<button>Print me</button>
```

**script**

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<table id="printTable" border="1" rules="all">
```

Comment: i cant modify the table by putting `border="1" cellspacing="0"` it will change the styles

Comment: can we add style through javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new document in a new window, without including any style sheet, so the content is displayed and printed according to browser defaults. You need to include the relevant style sheet(s) in the new document, directly in a `style` element (or `style` attributes) or indirectly via a `link` element.

Comment: can we add style through javascript

Comment: when i added styles using javascript also its not picking up jsfiddle.net/x2d7otd1/2

Comment: @AlexMan, your jsfiddle uses wrong markup: change `<styles>` to `<style>` in the start tag and to `</style>` in the end tag.

Answer (score 0):

Okkay..Thanks For Your Reply...

You Can Have To Use STYLE After

```
<table id="printTable">
```

Like This [SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/x2d7otd1/4/)

OR You Can Put Style sheet in another .css file then include them after

```
    <table id="printTable">
```

I Think It Will Work For You

Comment: i don't want to print the whole page

Comment: when i added styles using javascript also its not picking up http://jsfiddle.net/x2d7otd1/2/

Comment: how to remove the Action column

Comment: Can You Please Tell Me Clearly??

Comment: when i click the print, i want to print the table except the Actions column, i dont want Actions to be printed