# Removing a html table first column after receving the html content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created an application for getting the table content as html in javascript, The application is working fine, but the issue is that after getting the html content in javascript i want to remove the first column from the javascript html table content

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ggm1r4ko/)**

```
function printData() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable");
    alert(divToPrint.outerHTML);
}

$('button').on('click', function () {
    printData();
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone the element, remove the first-child `td`s and the first `th` and then read the `outerHTML` of the cloned element:

```
$(divToPrint).clone()
             .find('th:first-child, td:first-child').remove().end()
             .prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: do you have any solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397534/table-border-line-is-removed-when-printing

Comment: @AlexMan You are welcome, regarding your another question, the new document doesn't have any linked css file, you can append a `link` to your printable document.

Comment: @AlexMan You have several options like cloning the target `link` and appending it to the new document's head. You can also create a printable document(another resource) and open it in a new window, the created document has the necessary links.

Comment: see this i have appended the styles to the javascript content, but still i am not getting anything http://jsfiddle.net/x2d7otd1/7/

Comment: @AlexMan You haven't closed the `style` element, I have updated the fiddle (_removed the `document.write` call_), it works on chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x2d7otd1/8/

Comment: one more help, can you please tell me how to remove the first row after the title in this example

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [Vohuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/vohuman)'s answer, I want to show how it can be done using Vanilla JS:

```
    function printData() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable");
        var tbody = divToPrint.children;
        var rows = tbody[0].children;
        for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
           rows[i].removeChild(rows[i].childNodes[0]);
            cells = rows[i];
            if (i==0) { cells.removeChild(cells.getElementsByTagName('th')[0]); }
            else { cells.removeChild(cells.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]); }
    }
        alert(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    }

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        printData();
    })
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggm1r4ko/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still we could able to do the task without any third part library that would be fine right

Answer (score 0):

```
/*this code has two sections or html pages.
Print.hmtl page execute the print task
Example.html page has the table you want,
in this case the table is tbl_show2. 
When you press the Print button in Example.html page
btnPrint function calls Print.html page and send two arguments.
contenido and titulo.

When Print.html page loads init() function is called.
In this function insert the HTML content of tbl_show2 in  
printTable div object. But HTML content has only the body section
this is the reason we add <table> and </table> tags to complete the 
table object. Then after that.  removefirstCol() remove the first column
and then the document is printed.*/


/*----------------Print.html-----------*/

<html>
<head>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
<!--

function removefirstCol(){
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printTable');
    for (var k = 0, len = divToPrint.children.length; k < len; k++){
        var tbody=divToPrint.childNodes[k];
        var rows = tbody.childNodes[1].children;
        len2=rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
            var row=rows[i];
            row.deleteCell(0);
        }
    } 
}


function init() {
    if (typeof window.dialogArguments == "object"){
        var objContenido = window.dialogArguments.contenido;
        var titulo = window.dialogArguments.titulo;
        document.getElementById('printTable').innerHTML='<table border=1 id="tbl_show" name="tbl_Show">'+objContenido.cuerpo+'</table>';
        removefirstCol();
        window.title=titulo;
    }
    window.print();
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="margin: 3px">
<div id='printTable'>
</div>

</body>
</html>

/*--------------------Example.html-----------------*/
<html>
<head>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
<!--

/*-----discomment this section for Chrome------------- 
window.showModalDialog = function (url, arg, feature) {
    var opFeature = feature.split(";");
    var featuresArray = new Array()
    if (document.all) {
        for (var i = 0; i < opFeature.length - 1; i++) {
            var f = opFeature[i].split("=");
            featuresArray[f[0]] = f[1];
        }
    }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < opFeature.length - 1; i++) {
            var f = opFeature[i].split(":");
            featuresArray[f[0].toString().trim().toLowerCase()] = f[1].toString().trim();
        }
    }
    var h = "600px", w = "1000px", l = "100px", t = "100px", r = "yes", c = "yes", s = "no";
    if (featuresArray["dialogheight"]) h = featuresArray["dialogheight"];
    if (featuresArray["dialogwidth"]) w = featuresArray["dialogwidth"];
    if (featuresArray["dialogleft"]) l = featuresArray["dialogleft"];
    if (featuresArray["dialogtop"]) t = featuresArray["dialogtop"];
    if (featuresArray["resizable"]) r = featuresArray["resizable"];
    if (featuresArray["center"]) c = featuresArray["center"];
    if (featuresArray["status"]) s = featuresArray["status"];
    var modelFeature = "height = " + h + ",width = " + w + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ",model=yes,alwaysRaised=yes" + ",resizable= " + r + ",celter=" + c + ",status=" + s;
    var model = window.open(url, "", modelFeature, null);
    model.dialogArguments = arg;
}   
//-----end google chrome section-----*/

function btnPrint(){
    var objArgs = {cuerpo: null};
    objArgs.cuerpo=document.getElementById("tbl_show2").innerHTML;
    window.showModalDialog("Print.html",{contenido: objArgs, titulo: 'Print Example'},"status:no;help:no;resizable:yes;dialogHeight:400px;dialogWidth:800px");
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1 id='tbl_show2' name='tbl_show2'>
<tr>
<td>columna 1
</td>
<td>columna 2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<input type="button" name='PrintMe' id='PrintMe' value="Print" language=jscript onclick="btnPrint();">
</html>
```

Comment: It would be good if you explained the code a bit instead of just pasting code?

Comment: Explain? There are two html pages. Only Use it!! Example.html has tbl_show2 table with many rows and many columns if you want. Print.html prints this table. That's all folk. Of course the first column of the table is deleted before print.